# Помогите пожалуйста решить ошыбку return loads(fp.read(), io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Tags: python

```
import json

numbers = {'Детр':"Макс", "Шульга": "Миша", "Кабальський": "Толик", "Асанов": "Антон","Юров": "Гриша"}

filename = "numbers.json"

with open(filename,"w") as f:

numbers = json.load(f)
```

Comment: `json.load` - чтение из файла, а у вас файл в режиме `"w"`, что значит только для записи. Как написано в ответе, уберите`"w"`, т.к. `open` по-умолчанию открывает файл в режиме `"r"` - чтение

Answer (score 1):

Команда

```
with open(filename,"w") as f:
```

держит файл открытым только для закончения последующего блока команд с отступами. Потому что у вас такого блока нет, файл закрытый.

Сделайте отступ:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    numbers = json.load(f)
```

Обратите внимание тоже на то, что я исключил параметр `"w"` из функции `open()`, потому что он не позволяет читать файл, а уничтожит его.